# How to apply sorting on ngx-datatable with grouping

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable component in my angular app. I have grouped the data using `[groupRowsBy]="'age'"`. I want to apply the sorting to grouped data, so i tried

```
[sorts]="[{ prop: 'age', dir: 'asc' }]"
```

but this is not working.

```
<ngx-datatable
    #myTable
    class='material expandable'
    [rows]="rows"
    [groupRowsBy]="'age'"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [scrollbarH]="true"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="40"
    [limit]="4"
    [groupExpansionDefault]="false"
    [sorts]="[{ prop: 'age', dir: 'asc' }]">
```

Here is the link to test

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-row-grouping-and-row-detail?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue still hasn't been resolved. See https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1329.
However, the solution maybe to manually change the order in rows adding custom sorting methods.
There is an event sort, so you can have smth like
`(sort) = "onSort($event)"`,
there you would have to take the name of the column and reorder rows in a way you want.
Hope that helps :)